# Return Tuple Element

Tags: solidity, remix

I have the following function with a tuple:

```
function getETHPrice() internal view returns (int) {
    (,int price,,,) = AggregatorV3Interface(ETH_USD_FEED).latestRoundData();
    return price;
}
```

How do I return the price without storing it in an intermediary variable?
In another language, I would do something like this:

```
return AggregatorV3Interface(ETH_USD_FEED).latestRoundData()[1]
```

How can i do that?
When I try that, I get the following error:

> `TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is tuple(uint80,int256,uint256,uint256,uint80))`

Comment: What's wrong with a local variable?

Comment: @MadJackal Nothing, I am just learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Solidity official documentation there is a [part about tuples](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#assignment)

> Tuples are not proper types in Solidity, they can only be used to form syntactic groupings of expressions.

You can use it as a return value but can't access a certain element in it. The way you do it in your code is the way to go, unfortunately. You could simplify it a bit by declaring a return variable like this if you would like:

```
function getETHPrice() internal view returns (int price) {
    (, price,,,) = AggregatorV3Interface(ETH_USD_FEED).latestRoundData();
}
```